# Returning a ZonedDateTime always from a Java TemporalAccessor with missing fields

Tags: java, datetime, time

I have a certain class that parses a (fairly) wide variety of dates:

```
// imports omitted for brevity

public final class DateParser
{
    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN 
            = "[h][hh][[:][.]mm][[ ]a][ v][ ][[EEEE ][E ][d][dd][/][-][LLLL][L][/][-][uuuu]]";

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN).localizedBy(Locale.ENGLISH);

    public static ZonedDateTime parseDateTimeString(final String dateTimeString)
    {
        TemporalAccessor parsedString = formatter.parse(dateTimeString);

        ZonedDateTime returnable = ZonedDateTime.now();

        // Return a ZonedDateTime with sane defaults if some fields are missing from parsedString
    }
}
```

I would like to return a `ZonedDateTime` that has sane defaults if parsedString is *not* a complete `ZonedDateTime`.

1. Say, for instance, that the string given to the method is `"5:45pm"` (which *will* parse successfully); I would like the ZonedDateTime to reflect 5:45 pm *today*, at the current time zone. Of course, a more pre-emptive way would be to reflect 5:45pm the *next* day if it is already past quarter to six today, but I'd like to get this implemented first.
2. Other possible inputs are just the day of week, for instance, `"Monday"`: this would return a `ZonedDateTime` set for the next Monday after the current day, at 12 pm, at the local time zone.
3. An input of just a date `"4/2/2020"` would return a `ZonedDateTime` set at the local time zone, the date in the input (the 4th of February, 2020), with time set at 12 pm.

How would I go about doing this? I currently have bit of code, that just consists of a very long chain of `if`s:

```
if (parsedString.isSupported(ChronoField.YEAR))
{
    returnable = returnable.withYear(parsedString.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
}            
if (parsedString.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH))
{
    returnable = returnable.withMonth(parsedString.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR));
}
if (parsedString.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)) 
{
    returnable = returnable.withDayOfMonth(parsedString.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
// And so on.
```

However, this merely modifies the current date-time group. I am not sure how to implement things like (2) and (3).

Furthermore, it possible to *build up* a `ZonedDateTime` from `parsedString`, by iterating over its fields, somehow? Or is there some other way to achieve this entire parsing idea?

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: I doubt you can do this with only a pattern, but you can certainly use `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN);` and then repeated calls to [parseDefaulting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting%28java.time.temporal.TemporalField,long%29) on that same builder.

Comment: @VGR, that’s precisely what I needed, and it works successfully. Goes to show once again that reading the Javadocs is important. Would you mind posting this as an answer, so I can mark it solved and give you some credit? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you can do this with only a pattern, but you can create a DateTimeFormatterBuilder and call its [parseDefaulting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting%28java.time.temporal.TemporalField,long%29) method:

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.appendPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN);

ZonedDateTime defaults = ZonedDateTime.now();

builder.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR,
       defaults.getLong(ChronoField.YEAR));
builder.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR,
       defaults.getLong(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR));
builder.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH,
       defaults.getLong(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
// etc.

DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();

ZonedDateTime returnable = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
```